# Accessing private vector in the header file within the class

Tags: c++, vector, private

I am trying to access a private vector array in the header class Polygon.h in my class Polygon.cpp  I tried using a getter, but it will not allow me to call the function with the instance of the class itself.  How would I go about this?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "point.h"

class Polygon {

private:
    std::vector<Point> pts;
public:

    Polygon();
    static Polygon parsePolygon(std::string s);
    std::string toString() const;
    void move(int dx, int dy);
    double perimeter() const;
    double area() const;
    int getNumVertices() const;
    bool operator == (const Polygon &p) const;
    double isperimetricQuotient() const;
    Point getIthVertex(int i) const {return pts[i];}
    std::vector<Point> const &getPolygon() const {return pts;}
};

//Polygon.cpp

#include "Polygon.h"
#include <string>

Polygon::Polygon()
{
    pts.resize(4);
    Point p1(-1,1); 
    Point p2(1,1);
    Point p3(1,-1);
    Point p4(-1, -1);
    pts[0] = p1;
    pts[1] = p2; 
    pts[2] = p3;
    pts[3] = p4;

}



static Polygon parsePolygon(std::string s)
{
int seperator;
int start = 1;
for(int i = 0; seperator != std::string::npos; i++)
{
seperator = s.find(")(");
std::string subPoint = s.substr(start, seperator);
getIthVertex(i) = Point.parsePoint(subPoint);
start = seperator + 1;
}

}

void move(int dx, int dy)
{
for(int i = 0; i < *this.getPolygon().size(); i++)
{

}
}
```

Comment: Your cpp's `parsePolygon` is a separate function from the one in the class. Same with `move`.

Comment: what's `std::vector<Point> const &() const {return pts;}` ? also your `void move(int dx, int dy)` is a free function.

Comment: @billz, Methinks someone forgot to name the function.

Comment: Why not write a small class with only the method you are having trouble with instead of posting mostly irrelevant code?

Comment: `parsePolygon` looks like it belongs more as a free function, and I would expect that to take a `const Polygon &`.

Comment: so how would i go about "including" the parsePolygon function?

Comment: Which is the error message?

Comment: two errors i get are "getIthVertex is undefined" and "this maybe only use inside a nonstatic member function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems. One obvious one is in the definition of the `move()` member function. It is never really defined: you have a non-member function of the same name. So, you have to define it in the `Polygon` scope. Next, `*this.size()` doesn't do what you think it does: it is parsed as `*(this.size())`. You don't need `this` anyway, so that one is easy to fix:

```
void Polygon::move(int dx, int dy)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < getPolygon().size(); ++i)
  {

  }
}
```

You have similar problems with the definition of `parsePolygon`, which should be

```
Polygon Polygon::parsePolygon(std::string s)
{
  ......
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.  Now to muddle to the other problems :(

Comment: @user2557642 it is usually more productive to deal with one problem at a time. So next time you post a question, try to create a small code sample that reproduces only one problem in isolation. It will be easier for people to help like that, plus you might even solve the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: will do. thanks a lot!  but how do we get parsePolygon to be included as well.  I tried adding the scope to it but it generates an error saying "the declaration is compatable when I try "Polygon::parsePolygon()"

Answer (score 0):

The definition of parsePolygon should be:

```
Polygon  Polygon::parsePolygon(std::string s) {
    ....
}
```